# Trying to Scrape Data from a Page That Doesn't Always Load (Python Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, exception, web-scraping

I'm trying to get the html of a page that only loads about 33% of the time.  My strategy is to just keep refreshing the page until it eventually loads.

I call this function from another, in which I've already initiated my driver (edited to include a try/catch block for the `while` statement as per @crookedleaf's suggestion:

```
def get_table(url, driver):
    driver.get(url)
    main_window = driver.current_window_handle
    html_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@title="View as HTML"]')
    html_button.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.RETURN)
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.TAB)
    driver.switch_to.active_element
    try:
        while 'extranet.chem' not in driver.title:
            sleep(2)
            print('refreshing to get data')
            try:
                html_button.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.RETURN)
            except Exception:
                print('deeper exception')
                driver.refresh()
    except:
        print('while exception')
        pass
```

I use a nested `except` to catch possible exceptions to my `driver.refresh()` call.  For some reason, even though I call `pass` to ignore exceptions, the loop breaks while looking for the driver's title:

the error message:

```
refreshing to get data
refreshing to get data
refreshing to get data
deeper exception
while exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraper.py", line 83, in <module>
    get_latest()
  File "scraper.py", line 28, in get_latest
    url = row.find_element(By.XPATH, link_xpath).get_attribute('href')
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 645, in find_element
    {"using": by, "value": value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 628, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 237, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of <tr class="ms-alternating"> is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed
```

Why is this exception not just being ignored?

Comment: Would you be able to add to your post the things you've tried, in order to bypass the UnexpectedAlertException?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the provided traceback, you can see the exception is being raised on the line `while 'extranet.chem' not in driver.title:`:

```
File "scraper.py", line 55, in get_table
    while 'extranet.chem' not in driver.title:
```

which is not in a `try/except` block. I'm not sure i've seen that exact exception raised while checking `driver.title`, but i suppose it is normal. Without knowing anything about the page you are working with, we aren't able to help you much more than that. your option is to catch the exception that is generated at that line. with an alert box being present, you will more than likely be prevented from navigating away from  or refreshing that page until the alert is dealt with. you should build in a way to handle the alert.

Comment: I've added a try/catch block to the while statement to see if it sheds any light on the problem.

Comment: What sort of info would you need on the page?  Besides the title, all I know is there should be a table that loads.  Would it be better to check for the existence of the table?

Comment: @DavidJ. without being able to go to the page ourselves, there isn't a lot we can do to provide specific help. the exception you're getting is because there's an alert on the page. if you aren't able to provide full reproducible code including the url, the only thing i can really suggest is looking at the page when that exception is raised, seeing what the alert says, and adding something to the code that clears the popup. if you're using PhantomJS, i don't think this is supported. but if you're using Chrome or Firefox, you can use `driver.switch_to.alert.accept()

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try it.  Unfortunately I can't give you a link to the page since it's on an extranet.